# Nexus 3 | How to create (external) users using Nexus 3 APIs?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to create external user on Nexus 3 using nexus 3 APIs. Following are the details:
Posting Groovy Script using: `http://localhost:8081/nexus3/service/rest/v1/script`

```
{
    "name": "d8b3baeb-628a-43cc-9a9c-9a156f399e2",
    "type": "groovy",
    "content": "security.addUser('q018246a', '', '', '', true, 'd8b3baeb-628a-43cc-9a9c-9a156f399ae2', ['abc_test_role Developer Role']);"
}
```

Running Script using: `http://localhost:8081/nexus3/service/rest/v1/script/d8b3baeb-628a-43cc-9a9c-9a156f399e2/run`

Response:

```
{
    "name": "d8b3baeb-628a-43cc-9a9c-9a156f399e2",
    "result": "User{userId='q018246a', firstName='', lastName='', source='default'}"
}
```

Hitting though Postman, all working fine and users getting created. But through Application server it is giving `Bad request`.

Awkward behavior is, it's letting me create user using postman post script with blank `first_name, last_name, email, password`, but all these parameters are required on UI.

Another thing, It's showing `source` as `default` but how to I ensure `source` as `LDAP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to map an LDAP user?  If so, this will work:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.role.RoleIdentifier;
import org.sonatype.nexus.security.user.User;

String userId = 'someuser';
String newRoleId = 'nx-admin'

User user = security.securitySystem.getUser(userId, 'LDAP')

if(user != null) {
    RoleIdentifier newRole = new RoleIdentifier('default', newRoleId);
    user.addRole(newRole)
    security.securitySystem.setUsersRoles(user.getUserId(), 'LDAP', user.getRoles());
} else {
    log.warn("No user with ID of $userId found.")
}
```

Comment: That'll work for an existing LDAP user. I'm trying to add a new user under the LAP realm.